# sed: extract and print regexp match group

Tags: command-line, sed

I'm trying to extract the IPv4 address of a network interface on Linux.
I have a working solution:

```
IFACE=eth0
ip a show dev $IFACE | sed -n 's/.*inet \(.*\)\/.*/\1/p'
```

For the record, here is a sample output of the `ip a show` command:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:51:51:b4:a9:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.20/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::251:56ff:fec1:4915/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

While my solution works, I'm wondering if there is a *sed way* to grab the content of the regex pattern match group and replace the current line (in sed terms, the *pattern space*) with it or print it somehow?
I consider having to use `s///p` and expanding the pattern to the whole line (with `.*` at the beginning and the end) to be a kludge.

Answer (score 5):

Parsing `ip` human-oriented output is a kludge. Use the JSON output:

```
ip -4 -json a show dev $IFACE scope global | jq -r ".[].addr_info[].local"
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but "jq" is usually not present on the machines. Also your solution prints a couple of extra "null" lines. My question is more about sed.

Comment: Using `jq -r '..|.local?|select( . != null)'` gets rid of the `null`lines.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove everything you don't want, e.g.: `sed -n 's:.*inet ::; T; s:/.*::p'`.

However, another approach is to use `ip -o -f inet` and standard tools, e.g. with `tr` and `cut`:

```
ip -o -f inet addr show dev eth0 | tr -s ' ' '/' | cut -d/ -f4
```

Comment: I appreciate the different suggestions however i specifially asked for a different way to do it with sed. So it's more of a sed question.

Comment: @neuhaus: `sed -n 's:.*inet ::; T; s:/.*::p'` is different